# Duplicate declaration of method

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I am working on a react native app and I don't have any experience with iOS (or native code) and I know I should learn.

I was following instructions from git repo and working on the [native side](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-react-native-plugin/blob/HEAD/Docs/Guides.md#url-schemes)

The code snippet required me to add this in code.

```
// Reports app open from deep link from apps which do not support Universal Links (Twitter) and for iOS8 and below
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString*)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    // version >= 6.2.10
    [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] handleOpenUrl:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];
 
    // version < 6.2.10
    [[AppsFlyerLib shared] handleOpenURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication withAnnotation:annotation];
    return YES;
}

// Reports app open from URL Scheme deep link for iOS 10
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary *) options {
    // version >= 6.2.10
    [[AppsFlyerAttribution shared] handleOpenUrl:url options:options];

    // version < 6.2.10
    [[AppsFlyerLib shared] handleOpenUrl:url options:options];
    return YES;
}
```

but I already have the following declaration

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
    return [RCTLinkingManager application:app openURL:url options:options];
    
}
```

Now, When I compile my app it throws an error saying

> error: duplicate declaration of method 'application:openURL:options:

Since both the declaration have a different return type, I think I can't merge them inside one declaration.

Can someone help me in fixing this error?

Comment: “Since both the declaration have a different return type” No they don’t.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {

BOOL handled = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
openURL:url
sourceApplication:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey]
annotation:options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey]
 ];

 // Add any custom logic here.
  BOOL deepLinking =  [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
return handled || deepLinking;
 }
```